# Web Service to Display a PDF, deleting the file once displayed

Tags: java, pdf, stream

I am attempting to display PDFs to the user in their browser using a web service.  Once they pass in the URL containing the variables needed.  My program first downloads the PDF to local storage then proceeds to copy it to the stream and displays it.  Once the viewer is able to view the PDF we wish to delete the file locally so that we do not wind up storing every file searched for.  I have managed to accomplish most of this task however I am having issues deleting the file once it is displayed to the user.

Even when I attempt to manually delete the file I receive the "Currently in use in the Java SE Binary" message

Code below:

```
File testFile = new File("C:\\Users\\stebela\\workspace\\my-app\\invoice"+invNum+".pdf");

try
{
    ServletOutputStream os = res.raw().getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream inputStr = new FileInputStream(testFile);
    IOUtils.copy(inputStr, os);

    os.close();
    inputStr.close();

    //finished settings
    res.status(200);
    testFile.delete();
} catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can you not store the file at all? Instead of storing it locally, just write it to the output stream of the response.

Comment: @Roman, Wouldn't that be same issue?  If I were to go IOUtils.copy(inputStr, res.raw().getOutputStream()); I'd still be using a stream that doesn't seem to want to let me delete the file.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be the same. If you don't create the file, you won't need to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't write to the file, you'r code should work.

If you call `inputStr.close();` the file is no longer used by java and it can be deleted.

Pleace check, if your file is not used by any other programm. It's the best if you reboot your PC.

If it still not works, it would be interessting to know, what res is and if your file get's sendet.

---

I've read [this part of the documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html) and i think this should solve your problem.

It reads the file into a String and change the header for png images. As the http Body it uses the String of the file.

Make sure, if you change the response type, you have to change the line `res.type("image/png");` to the new one.

[Here you find the most common ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Common_examples)

```
File testFile = null;
    try {
        testFile = new File("C:\\Users\\stebela\\workspace\\my-app\\invoice"+invNum+".png");

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(testFile);

    int charAsInt = 0;

    String httpBody = "";

    while((charAsInt = fin.read()) != -1){
        httpBody +=(char)charAsInt;
    }
    fin.close();

    res.body(httpBody);
    res.type("image/png");
    res.status(200);

    testFile.delete();


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: res is just the response of the java spark service (Request,Response).  The file is getting displayed in a browser which is the only time it is used.  Wondering why I can't delete the file post it's display.

Comment: If tried now a little bit with wireshark around and if think we could solve this problem.
It looks like, the spark framework holds the file in the cash.
If you're able to eddit the http(s) header and after this send the file loaded as a String. It should work.
Do you have the ability for changing the response header?